# Runtime Error - SIGSEGV

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am supposed to write a  program for adding array elements and remove the elements from the sum if the previous element is 0,but i'm getting Run Time error as **SIGSEGV**.How can i solve this error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,arr[10],n,sum=0;

    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d\n",&arr[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+arr[i];
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==0)
        {
            sum=sum-arr[i-1];
        }
    }

    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Pleote Indices of arrays start from 0.

Comment: If the size of the array `arr` is fixed at compilation, why are you asking the user to enter value for `n`? You should use a macro here. Read: http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx9b.html.

Comment: `scanf("%d\n",&arr[i]);` --> `scanf("%d",&arr[i]);`

Comment: `printf("%d", sum);` --> `printf("%d\n", sum);`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value(s)) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: if the first entry from the user is > 10, then undefined behaviour will result as the code accesses/sets values beyond the end of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem Here is size of the Array.
You declared array for size 10 and if the user enters the size as 100 then this kind of Run time error will appear.
To avoid this exception simply declare the array after user enters thee size i.e

```
     scanf("%d",&n);
     int arr[n];
```

Answer (score 3):

In this statement

```
sum=sum-arr[i-1];
```

when i is equal to 0 you are trying to access memory beyond the array.

Remove the new line character from the call of scanf

```
scanf("%d\n",&arr[i]);
         ^^
```

And if you ask the user to enter the number of elements of the array then you should check that the entered number is less than or equal to 10.
I think that it does not make sense to ask the user to enter the number of elements of the array. Otherwise it is better to use a Variable Length array if the compiler supports them.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   10

int main( void ) 
{
    int a[N];

    printf( "Enter %d elements: ", N );

    int n = 0;
    while ( n < N && scanf( "%d", &a[n] ) == 1 ) n++;

    long long sum = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( i + 1 == n || a[i+1] != 0 ) sum += a[i];
    }

    printf( "\nsum = %lld\n", sum );

    return 0;
}
```

If for example to enter the following sequence of numbers

```
1 2 0 3 4 0 5 6 0 7
```

then the output can look like

```
Enter 10 elements: 1 2 0 3 4 0 5 6 0 7

sum = 16
```

Comment: if No.of elements of array is user's choice then how to declare array length in above program @VIad from Moscow

Comment: @Pleotex If the compiler supports VLAs then you can just write int a[n]; where n was entered before the declaration.

Comment: @Pleotex Otherwise you can dynamically allocate the array using malloc.